# How do you make sure a txt file with a dictionary in it can't be edited?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I am trying to add save files to my text-adventure game that can't be edited by the user. This is so that they can't cheat by editing the dictionary inside of it. So far all I've done is a few algorithms that can be easily bypassed if you connected the dots. Basically it's this.

```py
import sys,os,ast
dictionary = {...}
save_dictionary = {...}
def save():
    filehandler = open("dictionary.txt", "a")
    data = str(dictionary)
    filehandler.write(data)
    filehandler.close()

def savecode():
    savecode = dictionary.values()
    total = sum(savecode)
    save_dictionary['savecodes'] = round(math formulas)
    filehandler = open("save_dictionary.txt", "a")
    data = str(save_dictionary)
    filehandler.write(data)
    filehandler.close()

def load():
    with open('dictionary.txt') as f:
        data = f.read()
        save = ast.literal_eval(data)
        f.close()
```

But the problem I'm facing is that it is easily by-passible if you just add an amount and equally subtract an amount, which would make the sum the same, making everything work the same. I did make it so that anytime the game itself detects any changes it immediately deletes all save files and makes you start over.

So is the solution making the files unable to be accessed at all? Or is it that the python file will detect the time it was created? I have no idea. It could be another option.

Comment: There is not much you can do.  Knowledgeable users can defeat any such limitation, given that the program code itself is in their control.

Comment: True, I am releasing the games as exe and dmg using py2exe and py2app. I have tested and it works just fine. So they won't have access to the main source code of the game itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hide files from the super user. They bought their computer and they reserve the right to read and edit whatever files they please. And no program will ever have higher permissions than the administrator.

Your best bet is to encrypt the data inside the file. So that if the user tries to edit, the program won't function properly.

A question that might be more relevant:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48629/how-do-i-prevent-memory-modification-cheats

Comment: I have decided to add 2 modes. Normal and disciplined mode. Normal will have no restrictions at all. But disciplined (or no cheat mode) I have added as an optional mode for anyone who wants it. I added it as some people might want to be forced to play the game the way it was coded.